# Lyapunov function for three-dimensional system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the system

$x'(t) = (\epsilon x(t) + 2y(t))(z(t)+1)\\ y'(t) = (-x(t)+\epsilon y(t))(z(t)+1) \\
z'(t) = -z(t)^3$

Construct a Lyapunov function and show that the basin of attraction of $(0,0,0)$ contains the region z > -1 when $\epsilon  $ is negative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $V=\frac{1}{4}x^2+\frac12y^2+\frac{1}{2}z^2$. Then
$$ V'(t)=\frac{1}{2}(1+z)\epsilon x^2+(1+z)\epsilon y^2-z^4 $$
and you will obtain the answer.